# String Manipulation ? and OOP issue JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, oop

Henlo,

My issue is that I have to create two objects using two different constructors:

```
public SmartHome(int size) {
       smrtDev = new SmartDevice[size];
   }

public SmartHome(SmartDevice[] values) {
       smrtDev = values;
   }
```

For the first one I've achieved it as so with this code snippet:

```
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter size of SmartHome: ");
        int size = myObj.nextInt();

        SmartHome firstSmartHomeObject = new SmartHome(size);

        for(int i=0; i<size;i++) {
            System.out.println("\nName: ");
            String name = myObj.next();
            System.out.println("\nLocation: ");
            double location = myObj.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("\nIs on?: ");
            boolean switchedOn = myObj.nextBoolean();
            firstSmartHomeObject.insertDevice(name, location, switchedOn);
        }
```

The second insertDevice() takes in `SmartDevice dev`
and I have no idea how to do so. What I've attempted is to do `SmartDevice dvc+(i) = new SmartDevice(name, location, switchedOn);` at the end of the loop but have no idea on how to create dvc1/dvc2/dvc3 etc... , not even sure if this would be the correct way to tacle this problem :(

Comment: You don't have to create a new variable (with different name) in each iteration of the loop. Just call it `dvc` and thats it.

Comment: use factory design pattern

Comment: @sri OP is learning language/programming basics, throwing design patterns at him is a bad idea imo.

Comment: so at the end of the loop i should have: ```SmartDevice dvc = new SmartDevice(name, location, switchedOn);``` ```secondSmartHomeObject.insertDevice(dvc);``` ?

Comment: @Amongalen I can have a look at factory design pattern since I'm at my first year of university studies and in the last few weeks we've only learnt about COMPOSITION, EXTENDS, CONSTRUCTORS, SUPERCLASSES. I'll probably have to learn about 'factory design pattern' in the near future anyway.

Comment: Yep, exactly. That should be just enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Supposed to do:  :s

```
SmartDevice dvc = new SmartDevice(name, location, switchedOn); secondSmartHomeObject.insertDevice(dvc);
```